# hover on links doesn't work because of z-index

Tags: hover, z-index

My footer is on z-index:-999, and cuz of this the hover s not working on the footer texts or links, but i can see them. I have to keep the z-index. Is there any procedure for the hover to work?

Answer (score 0):

No, anything that has a z-index of -1 (this is the lowest as far as I'm aware, -999 is irrelevant), is not inter-actable, as it's technically behind the `<HTML>` element.

I'm sure someone will clear that up if I'm wrong.

You'll need to post code for more help. As the fix is to remove such a z-index.

Comment: yes you are right ...but the thing is that i tried also with just -1 and still the hovers not working, but my footer has to be in minus cuz its under something

Comment: You'll have to figure out a way to make sure your footer isn't -1 then :) As I said, if you post the full code in a fiddle or something, you'll get better responses.

Comment: okey i ll try, its my first post so i dont know how s working here^^ thanks

Comment: but wihtout z-index i dont know how can i put under my footer

Comment: Post your code on here: http://jsfiddle.net/ - and edit your question when it's a full working example. You don't really ever want to set a z-index of -1 on anything, if you can help it.